# Enums and Console.WriteLine's behavior

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

So, I'm reading through my little book about VB.NET. I get to the chapter about constants. I'm currently reading about enumerations, and my mind is blown. Well, not really but I need to know why this happens. So it goes like this.

I create an enumeration list, like so.

```
Enum myEnum
    FOO = 0
    BAR = 1
End Enum
```

Now I want to write the value of the enumeration "FOO" to the console.

```
System.Console.WriteLine("FOO = {0}", myEnum.FOO)
```

However, the console spits out the name of the enumeration instead.

```
"FOO = FOO"
```

So, if I want to see the value that FOO stores I have to cast it.

```
System.Console.WriteLine("FOO = {0}", CInt(myEnum.FOO))
```

and the output looks like this, and all is well.

"FOO = 0"

Now, what confuses me about this is...

```
Option Strict On

Dim myVar As Integer = myEnum.FOO
```

How come I'm not required to cast myEnum.FOO in this statement to assign the value to myVar? Does this have more to do with Console.WriteLine's behavior? I'm dieing to know what's going on here. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there's an implicit conversion from enums to their underlying types - but that doesn't mean the conversion happens automatically without you indicating that you want it (e.g. by assigning to an Integer variable). This isn't really about `Console.WriteLine` - it's string.Format, or just calling `ToString`  on an enum value.

Comment: (I'm not adding that as an answer as I'm not sufficiently confident in VB's conversion rules to say for sure.)

Comment: VB.NET allows an implicit conversion from enum to integer.  But not the other way around.

Comment: I'm a C guy, and I haven't done a lot of OOP programming. I'm having trouble getting use to the fact that everything is an object, Haha. It seems to me that an enumeration member in VB.NET is not only storing a particular value, but also it's own handle/name?

Comment: Hans explained it.  `Dim myVar As Integer = myEnum.FOO` creates an integer variabe and casts the enum to integer.  `Dim myVar As myEnum` would be a `myEnum` type and print the name

Comment: I kind of get it now. What about this. `If myEnum.FOO = 0 Then...` In this statement am I comparing a myEnum to an Integer?

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I was failing to see myEnum as it's own type. Even though it's base type is an Integer it is ultimately it's own data type. Thanks for the help!

Comment: All `Enums` have a numerical type and that is `Integer` by default.  This: `Enum myEnum` is actually equivalent to this: `Enum myEnum As Integer`.

Comment: Right, but if this is the default why does System.Console.WriteLine require a type conversion from myEnum to Integer?

Comment: What confuses me even more is  that with the exception being `System.Console.WriteLine()` these implicit conversions are happening with `Option Strict On`. What am I missing?

Comment: I think I'm just confusing myself. I have now learned that I can print the enumeration value like so `System.Console.WriteLine("FOO = {0:D}", myEnum.FOO)` Which still confuses me more but, cool.

Comment: I'll end it with this. Like @JonSkeet said, it seems to have more to do with the ToString() method. Also, correct me if I'm wrong but when `Option Strict` is on VB.NET will implicitly convert **ONLY** for widening type conversions.